# MacBook multi-touch trackpad support

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, multi-touch

Why is 3-4 finger multitouch support not available (not even listed as trackpad preference options) on my late 2008 white plastic Mac book?

Comment: The question about a 2009 MacBook has some good discussion relating to the hardware difference between solid state and multitouch trackpads - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/make-solid-state-scrolling-trackpad-behave-like-multi-touch-trackpad/15296#15296

Answer (score 4):

The trackpad in the 2008 white plastic MacBook isn't capable of supporting multitouch gestures. As it's a hardware limitation -- meaning the trackpad hardware can't sense input from 3-4 separate fingers at once -- there aren't any hacks to get around the limitation.

One way to get full multitouch support would be to get a [Magic Trackpad](http://www.apple.com/magictrackpad/). They'll work with any bluetooth-enabled Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard v10.6.4 or later.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, although the apple support line guy (and his supervisor) thought they should work on my MacBook. Since the magic trackpad is described as for desktop macs, I think I'll take my MacBook to the Apple store and see it work before I buy one.

Comment: It's for notebooks too. The copy on the linked page also says "Use it in place of a mouse or in conjunction with one on any Mac computer — even a notebook."