# Are non-unibody MacBook Pros capable of Lion's 3 and 4 finger multi-touch gestures?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, multi-touch, non-unibody

Are non-unibody MacBook Pros (Late 2006 ~ Early 2008) capable of Lion's 3 and 4 finger multi-touch gestures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - [that era of hardware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19685/macbook-multi-touch-trackpad-support) is a [solid-state trackpad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/make-solid-state-scrolling-trackpad-behave-like-multi-touch-trackpad/15296#15296), not a multitouch trackpad and can only track one motion. Although it can guess fairly well if it's one finger or two that is moving in two dimensions (left-right and up-down), but that's all the hardware can tell.

Put another way, yours tracks the center of all touch points combined, not several touches individually at the same time with their own motion.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I figured as much.

Now, I notice the MB466 (2008, aluminum, "non-Pro") MacBooks have glass touchpads that resemble those on newer MBP's. Are these multitouch actually enabled, or do they share the same hardware restrictions as the non-unibody MBP's?

Comment: All of the glass trackpads have multitouch. All of the ones with the lower wide physical button do not*. (* The only "unibody" mac I can recall having a physical button and multi touch is the first generation Air.)

Comment: Actually this is not completely right, as my old MBP (early 2008, last non-unibody) does support all kinds of of multi-touch gestures, at least when using bettertouchtool ( http://blog.boastr.net/ ) and it does have a distinct button.

Comment: Even without BetterTouchTool, my MBP 17" (Early 2008) supports the same gestures in Lion as the unibody MBPs. However, with the smaller trackpad surface and the physical button in the way, the 3-finger + thumb pinch/spread gestures are cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** - but only the very late ones, like 2008ish - at least my early 2008 MBP (last non-uniboby) supported all kinds of multi-touch gestures using [bettertouchtool](http://blog.boastr.net/) - didn't try Lion on it but in the last Snowleopard versions all the OS X multi-touch gestures also worked.

Answer (score 1):

***No***

Also notice the following:

- the trackpad is **smaller**
- scrolling with **inertia** is not enabled!

***Fix***

When connecting the **external multitouch trackpad** by Apple, **all** those features get enabled. They do run smooth.