# Three Finger Gesture on 2007-2008 Macbook Pros

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Is the three finger gesture supported for the 2007-2008 nonunibody macbook pros? Wondering if I can change spaces on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry.

See this: [Are non-unibody macbook pros capable of lion's 3 and 4 finger multi-though gestures?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34178/are-non-unibody-macbook-pros-capable-of-lions-3-and-4-finger-multi-touch-gestur)

And this: [Pinch to zoom on macbook pro 2007](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53251/pinch-to-zoom-on-macbook-pro-2007)

If you would like to use these gestures you can buy a magic trackpad or magic mouse from Apple.

Comment: So, it should work only on a non-unibody 2008 then?

Comment: If you're lucky, and have a very late non-unibody, it might work using bettertouchtool, mentioned in the linked questions. But if the option is not present in System Preferences, you're likely out of luck.