# Pinch to Zoom on Macbook Pro 2007

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, multi-touch

I have an early 2007 Macbook Pro. The trackpad isn't multitouch - it doesn't support any of Lion's new many-finger gestures - but it does support two-finger scrolling. It obviously can keep track of two points of touch, so is there any way to get it to support pinch-to-zoom as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it can only discern between one narrow touch moving and one wider touch. It's not tracking multiple points - just calculating the area of touch and the single general motion.

Some other questions here might help explain this better:

- [Are non-unibody MacBook Pros capable of Lion's 3 and 4 finger multi-touch gestures?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34178/are-non-unibody-macbook-pros-capable-of-lions-3-and-4-finger-multi-touch-gestur)
- [MacBook multi-touch trackpad support](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19685/macbook-multi-touch-trackpad-support)
- [Make Solid-state scrolling trackpad behave like Multi-Touch trackpad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/make-solid-state-scrolling-trackpad-behave-like-multi-touch-trackpad)

No amount of software will make up for your solid state based trackpad. You might be able to get a Magic Trackpad or use an iOS device to inexpensively upgrade your hardware set and take advantage of multitouch.

Comment: OK, thanks... I guess I'll just either buy a Magic Trackpad or use my iPod Touch.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/). I don't know if it will support your Mac, but if it's at all possible I would expect it to.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support it... Thanks anyway, though!